# Prove that $S_4$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The question is to prove that $S_4$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$. [Here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/sym4-has-no-subgroup-isomorphic-to-the-quaternion-group/) is an answer. But what "then $H$ also contains all products of two 2-cycles" means in that answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $H$ contains the $4$-cycle $\sigma=(a\,b\,c\,d)$, because $H$ contains all $4$-cycles.  Squaring $\sigma$ gives the double transposition $(a\,c)(b\,d)$, which lies in $H$ by closure under products.  This is a generic double transposition (i.e. a "product of two $2$-cycles"), so $H$ contains all the double transpositions, i.e. $H$ contains the Klein $4$-group $V_4$.

Now $H$ contains at least $6$ elements (from the $4$-cycles), as well as $4$ new elements: those from $V_4$.  Thus $\vert H \vert \geq 10 >8$, and this is the claim that the author wants.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the argument computationally. $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$, is the group [`SmallGroup(8,4)`](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.4) in the [GAP Small Groups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html). In the following lines, I apply [`GAP`](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html) to probe the case:

```
gap> s4:=SymmetricGroup(4);;
     e:=AllSubgroups(s4);
```

This returns $30$ subgroups, but only three of them are of order $8$. Let's find them as follows:

```
gap>  Filtered(e,t->Order(t)=8);


Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (3,4) ]),
Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4) ]),
Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3), (2,4) ]),
```

Now, a simple code `StructureDescription(...)` tells us that the above subgroups are all $D_8$, not $Q_8$.

Comment: Of course this calculation verifies the statement, but does not follow the proof to which the original question refers to. It is easy to follow the steps of the argument using products of two 2-cycles in GAP as well.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: May I have your idea in detailed? :-) However, having minus vote tells me that `the set of all persons who dislike my behavior for such these kinds of problem` is not the empty set. Thanks Alexander.

Comment: Something like comparing `List(QuaternionGroup(8),Order);` with `Filtered(SymmetricGroup(4),t->Order(t)=4);`. One could also ask `Size(Group(Filtered(s,t->Order(t)=4)));` to see what their closure would be.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a square with vertices labelled by $1,2,3,4$. The group of symmetries of this square is dihedral group of order $8$, and its elements can be written as permutations on four letters.

Hence the dihedral group of order $8$ is subgroup of $S_4$ and $S_4\leq S_5$.

Since the order of Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $S_5$ is $8$, the Sylow-$2$ subgroup should be dihedral group of order $8$. Hence quaternion group of order $8$ can not be in $S_5$ (o.w. it would be Sylow-$2$ subgroup, not isomorphic to dihedral group).